# std::variant behaves differently in MSVC and gcc

Tags: c++, std-variant

**Update**: This is a C++ standard defect, which is fixed in C++20 (P0608R3). Also, VS 2019 16.10 has fixed this bug with `/std:c++20`.

MSVC 19.28 rejects the following code but gcc 10.2 accepts it and outputs `true false`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

int main()
{
    std::variant<long long, double> v{ 0 };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::holds_alternative<long long>(v) << ' ' << std::holds_alternative<double>(v) << std::endl;
}
```

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant):

> 4. Converting constructor. Constructs a variant holding the
>    alternative type `T_j` that would be selected by overload resolution for
>    the expression `F(std::forward<T>(t))` if there was an overload of
>    imaginary function `F(T_i)` for every `T_i` from `Types...` in scope at the
>    same time, except that:
>    An overload `F(T_i)` is only considered if the
>    declaration `T_i x[] = { std::forward<T>(t) };` is valid for some
>    invented variable `x`;
>    Direct-initializes the contained value as if by direct non-list-initialization from `std::forward<T>(t)`.

And the question is converted to which function of `F(long long)` and `F(double)` is selected agianst argument `1` by overload resolution.

Converting `int` to `long long` is an integral conversion (supposing `sizeof(long long)` is bigger than `sizeof(int)`) and converting `int` to `double` is an floating-integral conversion, neither ranks higher that the other. So the call is ambiguous and the program is ill-formed.

MSVC does rejected the code as I expected but to my surprise, gcc accepts it. Besides, there is also a similar example on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant):

```
std::variant<std::string> v("abc"); // OK
std::variant<std::string, std::string> w("abc"); // ill-formed
std::variant<std::string, const char*> x("abc"); // OK, chooses const char*
std::variant<std::string, bool> y("abc"); // OK, chooses string; bool is not a candidate
/* THIS ONE -> */ std::variant<float, long, double> z = 0; // OK, holds long
                                         // float and double are not candidates
```

So my question is: is gcc or MSVC non-conformance, or my understanding is wrong?

Comment: *"supposing sizeof(long long) is bigger than sizeof(int)"*, Have you checked that in both configuration?

Comment: FWIW, [clang seems to accept it as well](https://godbolt.org/z/83er5q).

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm pretty sure.on my system (Windows 10).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the quoted rule, an overload is considered only if **copy-list-initialization** for the candidate type works from the argument type.  This check doesn’t (can’t) consider the constant-expression status of the argument, so `int` to any floating-point type is a **narrowing** conversion and is disallowed by list-initialization (despite the fact that on typical implementations `double` can exactly represent every value of `int`).  GCC (*i.e.*, libstdc++) is therefore **correct** to disregard the `double` alternative.

Comment: The stadard wording is ``T_i x[] = { std::forward<T>(t) };`` which considers the value of the argument. So I'm afraid you are wrong.

Comment: Although list initialization prohibits narrowing conversion, but ``std::forward`` effectively performs an explicit conversion. For example, both ``float f1[] = { std::forward<float>(1) };`` and ``float f2[] = { std::forward<float>(0xffffffffffffffffuLL) };`` are valid.

Comment: @方圆圆: It’s `float f[]={std::forward<int>(t)};` that is checked: `T` is the argument type, not the fictitious parameter (*i.e.*, alternative) type.  Similarly, `t` is the parameter, not the argument, so it’s never a constant expression; detecting that the argument is a constant expression is unimplementable.