# Why does std::variant behave differently on GCC 8.5 and GCC 12.1 in respect to a `const char *` literal?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, std-variant

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

int main()
{
    std::variant<std::string, bool> v{ "hasta la vista" };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::holds_alternative<std::string>(v) << ' ' << std::holds_alternative<bool>(v) << std::endl;
}
```

#### GCC 12.1.1

```
$ g++ std_alternative.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
true false
```

#### GCC 8.5.0

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 std_alternative.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
false true
```

Why is the output different? Which is correct according to c++17? What should I do so that my code works on both versions of GCC the same way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65530460/stdvariant-behaves-differently-in-msvc-and-gcc

Comment: Looks like [LWG 3228](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3228), a defect in C++17 fixed by [P1957R2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1957r2.html). I guess GCC 8.5.0 doesn't have the fix backported.

Comment: Yes, that was a particularly nasty language defect, leading to totally unintuitive behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct explicit_bool {
  bool b = false;
  template<class T,
   std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, bool>, bool> = true
  >
  explicit_bool( T v ):b(v){}
  explicit_bool(explicit_bool const&) noexcept=default;
  explicit_bool& operator=(explicit_bool const&)& noexcept=default;
  explicit_bool()noexcept=default;
  ~explicit_bool()noexcept=default;
  bool operator!() const { return !b; }
  explicit operator bool() const { return b; }
};
```

store one of these (instead of a `bool`).

It only accepts actual `bool`s and other `explicit_bool`s as arguments.

You may have to add some explicit casts to-from `bool` in your code after doing this.  It may be of interest to you that `(bool)` as a cast always does the exact same thing as `static_cast<bool>` does, unlike many other C-style casts compared to C++ style casts; this can make it less painful.  Another choice is `!!`, which converts most types to `bool` implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

To workaround the problem on GCC 8.5, I am changing the variant to be

```
std::variant<std::string, const char *, bool> v{ "hasta la vista" };
```

That gives me a `const char *` on both GCC 12 and GCC 8. Looks like `const char *` wins over `bool`.

In the subsequent code, I then handle both ways of providing a string. It is IMO better than leaving the variant unchanged and requiring users to pass `std::string("hasta la vista")`, or dealing with the `""s` suffix magic. Either is easy to forget and then I am back in trouble!

Can't think of an even better way.

Comment: Be wary that raw pointers do not own their targets.  A `const char*` held in your variant may dangle before you want it to.